# User Concurrency is not working in Spark for hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-hive

I have configured 3 node Spark (version 1.4.0) cluster environment with Hive 0.13.1 version. and started Spark thrift service using **./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh**.

Multiple users are using same thrift service with same port and different usernames.

But the problem is that when one user executes query like **use mytest**. then database change is automatically reflects for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set hive concurrency values as mentioned in the docs:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-ConfigurationValuestoSetforINSERT,UPDATE,DELETE

```
Configuration Values to Set for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
In addition to the new parameters listed above, some existing parameters need to be set to support INSERT ... VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE.
Configuration key
Must be set to
hive.support.concurrency    true (default is false)
hive.enforce.bucketing  true (default is false)
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode    nonstrict (default is strict)
```

Comment: I changed above configuration settings but that also not works for me. 


And above properties (hive.enforce.bucketing & hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode) only works with (Hive 0.14.0 and later) and one more thing, Spark SQL doesn’t support buckets yet.